# Running ngrok in background

Tags: windows, ngrok

How can I run ngrok service in windows background. I have tried `ngrok http 80 --log=stdout > ngrok.log &` but it just hide the status if I close the ngrok.exe terminal, the service also get terminate. Is there any ways to let the ngrok.exe terminal run on windows background? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but you can [install Ngrok as a Windows service](https://ngrok.com/docs/secure-tunnels/ngrok-agent/installing-as-a-service/).

This link says you need to have a valid Ngrok config file (with your auth token and all your tunnels defined) and then run the following command:

```
ngrok service install --config C:\ngrok\ngrok.yml
```

and point to where you've saved your config file.

Then you can use Ngrok commands to start, stop, restart, and uninstall your service.

```
ngrok service start
ngrok service stop
ngrok service restart
ngrok service uninstall
```

I just did this today and it is working pretty well.

Hope this helps.